# Bash scripting - How to find the lines containing a certain string

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a script(let's say script1.sh) that find the lines that contain the words that I give, in files that are in a certain directory and its sub directories and only those that are in the files with certain a file extension. So `./script1.sh python py this.is.what.i.look.for` should give results like these:

```
python/abc/file1.py:11:    this.is.what.i.look.for and the line can contain other things as well
python/file2.py:412: this.is.what.i.look.for this.toggleButton.getElement())
```

I've tried using grep -r to search in the sub directories and managed to find the lines.

```
grep -r -e $3 $1
```

gives me the lines but fails to weed out other files with different file extensions and I couldn't find a way to include $2 in the code. Also I failed to put the line numbers in the middle. I tried to split the output into 2 parts like this: `python/abc/file1.py:`    `this.is.what.i.look.for and the line can contain other things as well` with `awk -F " " '{print $1}` but couldn't put them back together. I wanted to assign the parts of the output of the grep function into variables and then put them back together but failed at that as well. `t1="grep -r -e $3 $1 | awk -F " " '{print $1}'"` I tried using " ", ' ' ,$() to assign values since I didn't know which one to use but none of them worked.

Comment: Does your system's version of `grep` support a `--include` glob match option?

Comment: Yes it supports that option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with GNU `grep`, you can use `--include` (and `--exclude`) to restrict the matches in a recursive grep, using a shell-style glob expression:

```
grep -r --include='*.py' -e pattern dir
```

You can add `-n` or `--line-number` to add the numbering. Finally, remember to quote the positional parameters - so

```
grep -nr --include="*.$2" -e "$3" "$1"
```

Comment: I didn't know about the -n and --include. Thank you very much for the explanation.